# Remote Desktop with Dynamic DNS

Tags: router, ip, dynamic-dns

I have router with Dynamic Address. And I have registered for DnyDns service so that the changing public IP wont be any problem for me. Now my requirement is I should be able to connect to my system/PC which is connected to my Router from literally any part of the world. How can I do that? I made port forwarding on my router and got nothing.

Router IP: 192.168.0.1
My PC IP: 192.168.0.10 (Dedicated)
Public IP: xx.xx.xx.xx(Masked to a DynDns Domain name)
 I can ping my public IP using DynDns, but not to my PC which is inside the network.
Please help me guys. Thank You.

Comment: Make and nodel of router may help get a better answer.  Alos OS on workstation.

Answer (score 3):

On your router, you'll forward port 3389 to your 192.168.0.10 machine. Once you do that, you'll be able to open an RDP session to the computer from an external machine using your DYNDNS url.

You'll also need to ensure that the 192.168.0.10 machine is accepting RDP requests. What operating system is it?